# Blender Python How to insert a keyframe through code to compositing node that has no input

Tags: python

Specifically, I'm trying to insert a keyframe on a Sun Beams node's x and y source position through code. This property has no input:

[image]

It is callable through `scene.node_tree.node.source` instead of `scene.node_tree.node.input`. `source` path doesn't have a keyframe insert on it, so I can't do what I can saw in the internet like `scene.node_tree.node.source.keyframe_insert('data.source[0]')` won't work.

My latest attempt is `scene.node_tree.node.keyframe_insert('source')` and here's the output:
[image]

I think there has to be a way to do this, because the source position in the node is keyframable when right click on it and press "Insert Keyframe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you want to use the entire array as the object you keyframe, so code something along these lines will add a keyframe at frame 1:

```py
node = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].node_tree.nodes["Sun Beams"]
node.source[0] = 0.0
node.source[1] = 1.0
node.keyframe_insert("source", frame=1)
```

Obviously you can replace the first line with whatever you need to select the node in your case and `frame` parameter is optional, defaulting to the current frame.